# PHP Stripping Dynamic content

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, strip

I got a url that I would like to grab part of the return text but I am not sure how to do so. Here is what my curl is currently returning:

```
<div class="bibleReadingsWrapper">
   <h4>Responsorial Psalm <a href="/bible/psalms/2:7">Ps 2:7bc-8, 10-12a</a></h4>
   <div class="poetry"> R. (8ab) <strong>I will give you all the nations for an inheritance.</strong><br>
      The LORD said to me, “You are my Son;<br>
      this day I have begotten you.<br>
      Ask of me and I will give you<br>
      the nations for an inheritance<br>
      and the ends of the earth for your possession.”<br>
      R. <strong>I will give you all the nations for an inheritance.</strong><br>
      And now, O kings, give heed;<br>
      take warning, you rulers of the earth.<br>
      Serve the LORD with fear, and rejoice before him;<br>
      with trembling rejoice.<br>
      R. <strong>I will give you all the nations for an inheritance.</strong><br>
      <h4>Alleluia <a href="/bible/matthew/4:23">See Mt 4:23</a></h4>
      R. <strong>Alleluia, alleluia.</strong><br>
      Jesus proclaimed the Gospel of the kingdom<br>
      and cured every disease among the people.<br>
      R. <strong>Alleluia, alleluia.</strong><br>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="bibleReadingsWrapper">
   <h4>Gospel <a href="/bible/matthew/4:12">Mt 4:12-17, 23-25</a></h4>
   <div class="poetry"> When Jesus heard that John had been arrested,<br>
      he withdrew to Galilee. <br>
      He left Nazareth and went to live in Capernaum by the sea,<br>
      in the region of Zebulun and Naphtali,<br>
      that what had been said through Isaiah the prophet <br>
      might be fulfilled:<br>
      <br>
      <em>Land of Zebulun and land of Naphtali,<br>
      the way to the sea, beyond the Jordan,<br>
      Galilee of the Gentiles,<br>
      the people who sit in darkness<br>
      have seen a great light,<br>
      on those dwelling in a land overshadowed by death<br>
      light has arisen.</em><br>
      <br>
      From that time on, Jesus began to preach and say,<br>
      “Repent, for the Kingdom of heaven is at hand.”<br>
      <br>
      He went around all of Galilee,<br>
      teaching in their synagogues, proclaiming the Gospel of the Kingdom,<br>
      and curing every disease and illness among the people. <br>
      His fame spread to all of Syria,<br>
      and they brought to him all who were sick with various diseases<br>
      and racked with pain,<br>
      those who were possessed, lunatics, and paralytics,<br>
      and he cured them. <br>
      And great crowds from Galilee, the Decapolis, Jerusalem, and Judea,<br>
      and from beyond the Jordan followed him.<br>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I just want to pull the last (Gospel) part: `Mt 4:12-17, 23-25`

With the entire text of the gospel:

`When Jesus heard that John had been arrested,<br>he withdrew to Galilee. <br>He left Nazareth and went to live in Capernaum by the sea,<br>in the region of Zebulun and Naphtali,<br>that what had been said through Isaiah the prophet <br>might be fulfilled:<br><br><em>Land of Zebulun and land of Naphtali,<br>the way to the sea, beyond the Jordan,<br>Galilee of the Gentiles,<br>the people who sit in darkness<br>have seen a great light,<br>on those dwelling in a land overshadowed by death<br>light has arisen.</em><br><br>From that time on, Jesus began to preach and say,<br>“Repent, for the Kingdom of heaven is at hand.”<br><br>He went around all of Galilee,<br>teaching in their synagogues, proclaiming the Gospel of the Kingdom,<br>and curing every disease and illness among the people. <br>His fame spread to all of Syria,<br>and they brought to him all who were sick with various diseases<br>and racked with pain,<br>those who were possessed, lunatics, and paralytics,<br>and he cured them. <br>And great crowds from Galilee, the Decapolis, Jerusalem, and Judea,<br>and from beyond the Jordan followed him.`

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why bother scraping the bible its available in 50 million different formats, one of them is got to be what you want

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for a task like this. It's as simple as the following:

```
$html = str_get_html("HTML_STRING"); 
$e = $html->find("div[class=poetry]", 0);
echo $e->plaintext;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#download here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
#example to
include('simple_html_dom.php') 


$html = file_get_html('http://yourpage.com/');
$resultArr= array();
foreach($html->find('div.poetry') as $e)
    $temp =$e->innertext;
    array_push($resultArr,$temp);

echo $result = $resultArr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use html parser library or using jQuery or javascript

php library for same is here

https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser